# How to show a button after two scroll events

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm trying to make a 'back to top' button that appears after people have scrolled twice on a certain page.
I Found the following code online for a button that appears after the user scrolls down 20px but I can't seem to work out how to adapt it so it happens on two scroll events. Please help

```
<button onclick="topFunction()"id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<script>
    // Get the button
    let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    window.onscroll = function() {
      scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    function topFunction() {
      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Two scroll events"?

Comment: change the scrollFunction in charge of the scroll event so that it will keep track of the occurrence in a larger scope variable and check that condition in that same handler before deciding to change the visibility of the given element

Comment: i mean when people use the scroll wheel twice to go down

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `style` of the `myBtn` to `none` by default, and set its position to `fixed` to be fixed with the screen and not gone with scrolling.

```js
    // Get the button
    let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    window.onscroll = function() {
      scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    function topFunction() {
      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()"id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```